# How to prevent vuex state from resetting while using Secure-ls?

Tags: vue.js, security, local-storage, vuex, persistent-storage

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-ls to compress and encrypt my vuex ouath info, and vuex-persistedstate to make it persist after page refresh. every this is ok and work well, but something weird is happening when i'll add **encodingType: "aes"** to secure-ls options. it makes the persist not working anymore, i mean when i refreshing the page, the state is gone.
 how should i fix this?

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import oauthTokenModule from "./modules/oauthToken";
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";
import SecureLS from "secure-ls";

const ls = new SecureLS({ encodingType: "aes", isCompression: true });

Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    oauthTokenModule
  },
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState({
      paths: ["oauthTokenModule"],
      storage: {
        getItem: key => ls.get(key),
        setItem: (key, value) => ls.set(key, value),
        removeItem: key => ls.remove(key)
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-ls#api-documentation which needs an encryptionSecret, so if we forget to set this option, then in every refresh your vuex data will be discarded. by the way if you want to use secure-ls, you should pass to it an object like below:

```
{
    encodingType: "aes",
    encryptionSecret: "along and specific key here",
    isCompression: true
  }
```

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-browser-fingerprint to have a good key per browser, so the full answer can be like below for production mode only :

```
//securityOptions.ts";
import simpleBrowserFingerprint from "simple-browser-fingerprint";
const securityOptions = {
  encodingType: "",
  encryptionSecret: undefined,
  isCompression: false
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production")
  Object.assign(securityOptions, {
    encodingType: "aes",
    encryptionSecret: simpleBrowserFingerprint(),
    isCompression: true
  });
export default securityOptions;

//store.js
import securityOptions from "@/store/securityOptions";
const ls = new SecureLS(securityOptions);
```

Note: please Consider that this not a golden key to your problem, but have sth for security is better than not to have anything.